# The folder "www" doesn't seem to work properly on hostgator

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting

I've developed a website using Yii framework and now I need to move it to hostgator cheap hosting for a single site. It looks like it expects that the website must be placed into the root folder but my website has a www folder with index.php and resource files like js,css,images,etc. Also this folder contains a file htaccess with following content:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But I suppose I have to add another htaccess into the root folder so all requests will redirect to the www folder. (I did it and tried different combinations of the rewrite rules but they didn't work properly). I'm guessing I should remove htaccess from the www folder and leave only one in the root folder. 
Sorry guys, I always have problems with htaccess even after reading documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the `www` directory not be set as your document root? I am sure HostGator allows you to place directories and files *above* the document root (normally `public_html`).

Comment: Cpanel shows me some paths: Web root - `/home/mysitename`   Working directory - `/home/mysitename/public_html`    But I can't get access to the folder `/home/mysitename`  via ftp. I can get access only to `/home/mysitename/public_html`    So I suppose I have only one option: to add a redirect to a folder `/home/mysitename/public_html/www`   and to store Yii files in  `/home/mysitename/public_html`   That's why I need to fix conflicts between htaccess files. Also I can't use Addon domains because I use a hosting package "Hatchling" and it doesn't allow to use them.

Comment: You could simply move the `.htaccess` file into `public_html` and change the rule to `RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]`. That said, any host that doesn't allow you access to your site's home directory is silly. I have free hosting in my country that allows it, so I don't know what Hostgator's problem is on that front.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The server shows a file list instead. I found  this [htaccess](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/347). It works for the home page but it shows `404` for pages like `http://my_domain/somepage`.

Comment: Then perhaps try placing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]` in `/.htaccess` and then place `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` in `/www/.htaccess`. Remember to have `RewriteEngine On` in both files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can configure your domain as an addon domain with the document root set in www as you prefer.

Of course I am presuming that you have cPanel on Hostgator.